# Incremental loading of files from On-prem file server to Azure Data Lake

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake, azure-data-factory

We would like to do incremental loading of files from our on-premises file server to Azure Data Lake using Azure Data Factory v2.

Files are supposed to store on daily basis in the on-prem fileserver and we will have to run the ADFv2 pipeline on regular intervals during the day and only the new un-processed files from the folder should be captured.

Answer (score 0):

Our recommendation is to put the set of files for daily ingestion into /YYYY/MM/DD directories.  You can refer to this example on how to use system variables (@trigger().scheduledTime) to read files from the corresponding directory:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/how-to-read-write-partitioned-data

Answer (score 0):

In the source dataset, you can do file filter.You can do that by time for example (calling datetime function in expression language) or something else what will define new file. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-expression-language-functions
Then with a scheduled trigger, you can execute pipeline n times during the day.